# application redirect to IIS root folder during upload excel file in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, iis

I am facing issue in my web application which is made in asp.net. I have host the application on IIS server.and I am going to upload excel file to port data in database from application.when i uploading from locally from server itself its working fine but i when i try to uploading using public ip or outside then my application redirect to IIS root folder can any one tell me whats is the issue.

Answer (score 1):

this could be an permission issue on your web.config, file and folder permission or maybe a missing reference to correct folder.

**Web.config**
What is the authentication ? Do you allow Anonymous access. I understand that you can upload fine if you open the side from localhost from the server itself. Did you try to open the side with public ip from the server itself ?

**Application Pool in IIS**
Look for the "Identify" configuration and set this to "ApplicationPoolIdentify"

**File Permission**
Look for the folder and ensure that the "IIS_IUSERS" got write permissions

**Code** Try to sepecify the correct path using the server.MapPath()

```
Dim myPath As String = Server.MapPath("foldername") & "\" & "filename.csv"
```

Comment: please share the code snipped that you use for upload.